# PHP and fopen(), sometime works sometimes fails (last time answered "Resource id #17")

Tags: php, fopen

I've tried a solution to long scripts called throw cronjobs and problems with timeout (infact I needed to recover a lot of data and store it within a database 4 times a day).
So I've created a php page that calls, using fopen(), the same file multiple times with different vars so that the receiving file select\ different parts of data and store them.

I use fopen() like 10 times a file.

Here is part of the script:

```
 function call() {

     $time_start_insert = microtime(true);
     $server = "servername";

     // ***********  *********** OPEN PROCESSES lvl 1 ***********  
     echo "<div><br><i>************ Jobs Market Insert ************</i></div><br>";
     echo "<br><div><i>************ Server $server lvl 1 ************</i></div><br>";
     // ***********  *********** OPEN PROCESSES lvl 1 ***********       
     // open child process
     echo "<br><i><p class='start'>************ Lunched process 0-10 lvl 1 ************</i></p>";
     $numC = "10";
     $fromC = "0";
     $workSkill = "1";
     $fileName = urlencode("".ucfirst($server)." Job $fromC-$numC lvl $workSkill"); 
     $url = "http://URL.../dbjob.php?server=$server&csel=$numC&cfn=$fromC&joblevel=$workSkill&fname=$fileName";
     echo "<br>";
     print_r($url);     
     $child1j10 = fopen($url, 'r') or die("<br>Couldn't get file, so I'll retry<br>".print_r($url)."<br>".fopen($url, 'r'));
     echo_flush();

     // Output one line until end-of-file
     if($child1j10) {
        $buffer = stream_get_contents($child1j10);
        echo "<br>";
        echo "<br><b><p class='titles'>++++++++++++++This is response from process:++++++++++++++++++</b></p>";
        print_r($buffer);
        echo "<br><b><p class='endtitles'>--------------FINISHED process called job 10 lvl 1 --------------</b><br></p>";
        fclose($child1j10);
   }    
   echo_flush();

   // open child process
   echo "<br><i><p class='start'>************ Lunched process 10-20 lvl 1 ************</i></p>";
   $numC = "10";
   $fromC = "10";
   $workSkill = "1";
   $fileName = urlencode("".ucfirst($server)." Job $fromC-".($fromC+$numC)." lvl $workSkill");  
   $url = "http://URL/dbjob.php?server=$server&csel=$numC&cfn=$fromC&joblevel=$workSkill&fname=$fileName";
   echo "<br>";
   print_r($url);       
   $child1j20 = fopen($url, 'r') or die("<br>Couldn't get file, so I'll retry<br>".print_r($url)."<br>".fopen($url, 'r'));
   echo_flush();

   // Output one line until end-of-file
   if($child1j20) {
        $buffer = stream_get_contents($child1j20);
        echo "<br>";
        echo "<br><b><p class='titles'>++++++++++++++This is response from process:++++++++++++++++++</b></p>";
        print_r($buffer);
        echo "<br><b><p class='endtitles'>--------------FINISHED process called job 20 lvl 1 --------------</b><br></p>";
   fclose($child1j20);
   }    
   //stream_set_timeout($child1j40, 2700);
   echo_flush();
```

So I've launched the page and it worked for ex. for 6 times, than returns me:

```
 //from fist print_r
 http://URL/dbjob/dbjob.php?server=primera&csel=10&cfn=60&joblevel=2&fname=Primera+Job+60-70+lvl+2
 //from second print_r
 http://URL/dbjob.php?server=primera&csel=10&cfn=60&joblevel=2&fname=Primera+Job+60-70+lvl+2
 Couldn't get file, so I'll retry
 1
 Resource id #17
```

Can you understand why?
Thx.

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't do this `die("<br>Couldn't get file, so I'll retry<br>".print_r($url)."<br>".fopen($url, 'r'))` as `die` will make the script exit on this line. Also `fopen`will return result into the string and make as you can see it `Resource id #17` out of the ressource you get from `fopen`.

Comment: Thanks Charlotte, you are surely right about reasons for "resource id..." message, but the problem with sometime "false" answer from fopen() remain.

That was the reason Why I tried to force script reopen page with fopen...

Comment: Instead of using `or die` make an if condition after `fopen` and check if it returns false, if it does print message (**not** with `die`, but with `echo`) and reopen again with `fopen`. But I wouldn't be so sure that twice `fopen` will work if it already fails once.

Comment: I've made those changes, thx. But anyone know why sometimes works sometimes not? It's always the same file...

Comment: Enable error reporting. `fopen` throws an `E_WARNING` on failure.

Comment: I'm still waiting it happens again :D